# How to be sure my Mac is fully disconnected?

Tags: network, wifi, security, bluetooth, ethernet

On many occasion thinking that my Mac was disconnected from any form of network (with or without wire), I discovered that in fact it was
confortably chating at full speed with the rest of the world through
a forgotten connection. Typically:

```
tcpdump -i en1
```

displayed a high speed movie about `domain`, `bootpc`, `http`, `netbios`, `https`, `5223 (unassigned)`… trafics.

For the wireless side, there is a nice function to be aware that a Mac
is connected or not: the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar.

But for infrared, Bluetooth, Ethernet, MacOS X seems to miss the same usefull and simple function.

---

Is there a **trustable** software or method to be sure that a Mac if **fully** disconnected from **any** form of network?

I would be mostly interested by something as small and as visual as the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

This software should accomplish what you're looking for: ["Ethernet Status"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ethernet-status-lan-network/id834979136?mt=12)
There might be free alternatives, this is the first one I came across.